# How do I assign a user to a shared folder using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to select users from the drop-down list for the shared folder I created. How can I do this using Powershell?

The following script does add users under the security tab, but not under the sharing tab, when you click on the Share button.

[image]

[image]

So far my script is:

```
$Parameters = @{
    Name = 'Test'
    Path = 'C:\Test'
    FullAccess = 'SVR1\repl1', 'SVR1\repl2'
}
New-SmbShare @Parameters
```

Comment: Did you reload this window after running `New-SmbShare`? Does `Get-SmbShareAccess` return a list with the new share as expected?

Comment: Not really explicit where your screenshot comes from. Furthermore cmdlet work as expected as security tab is populated.

Comment: I have added the screenshot to my original question.
Thank you for your help in advance.